# WebRequest BeginGetResponse/EndGetResponse throws exception when using Task.FromAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, async-await, webrequest

I try to asyncify the POST operation to a REST web service using the WebRequest.

So from what I know already, I need to use the `Task.Factory.FromAsync<T>(BeginXyz, EndXyz, null)`, seems like its working for the `GetRequestStream` pair methods, since I get no exception and the byte[] is filled with values.

```
Stream requestStream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(
                        request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, null);
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);
await requestStream.WriteAsync(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
```

Fine, the above code is working, and the next part throwing the exception.

```
WebResponse webResponse = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(
                        request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);
```

The exception I get to every request.

> System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
>
> StackTrace:
>
> > at System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback
> >     beginMethod, Object state)    at
> >     System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
> >     asyncResult)    at System.Func`2.Invoke(T arg)    at
> >     System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
> >     iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
> >     requiresSynchronization)
> >     --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> >     task)    at
> >     System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> >     task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
> >     at
> >     Gtas.Core.ServiceRepository.d__8.MoveNext()
>
> InnerException StackTrace:   at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) at
>   System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClasse.b__d(Object
>   sendState) at
>   System.Net.Browser.AsyncHelper.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Object
>   sendState)

A full code to execute the request should be like that:

```
Stream requestStream = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<Stream>(
                        request.BeginGetRequestStream, request.EndGetRequestStream, null);
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData);
await requestStream.WriteAsync(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);


WebResponse webResponse = await Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(
                        request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);
Stream streamResponse = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
string responseString = await streamRead.ReadToEndAsync();
// ... Do something with the result data
```

I don't quite understand what the error is.

I tried several implementation from stackoverflow and some MSDN posts. Nothing seems to working.

Using callbacks working fine. But it's good to know why I can't make it work.

Any thoughts how to accomplish this?

Comment: Why is it you don't use something like HttpClient which supports Async/Await out of the box?

Comment: Hello, that would save my life, but since this is a library to distribute, i can't use third party libraries, meaning the end user will need two libraries. Dependencies are bad, in my case at least! Meaning HttpClient is only available through NuGet.

Comment: `NotSupportedException` seems to indicate something is missing from Xamarin's support. Have you asked them? (Async is still prerelease over there).

Comment: Stephen :) You have noticed the Xamarin word, to tell the truth, yes I use share code from the Xamarin projects, but the implementation is for Windows Phone 8, sorry for this, I only use the same namespace.

Comment: @George Taskos, I am developing for WP runtime in VS premium 2013 using Xamarin.Forms. I am also getting similar exception exactly in the same line you have given above in my PCL project. It works fine for Android & iOS. How to fix it? It would be helpful if you could post your answer here.

Answer (score 0):

1. try surround the requestStream with using or call requestStream.Close() after requestStream.WriteAsync
2. check the request.Method = "POST"; is not missing.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for memory leak but

```
WebResponse response = null;
using (var stream = await 
Task<Stream>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, result =>
{
    response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
    return response.GetResponseStream();
}, request))
{
    // TODO
}
response.Dispose();
```