# How to make a web service POST synchronous

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8, synchronous

I'll start that I understand the importance of asynchronicity and non UI-freeze application. The whole async/await world that I really love and even the APM, or doing heavy jobs using `Task`.

That's all fine, but I have a scenario that I really need to wait for the web service POST to finish and then continue.

```
public void DoSomeWorkNow()
{
   // Do stuff...
   // Do more stuff...
   // Make the web service call..
   // The request should finish and I should continue doing stuff....
   // Do stuff...
}
```

I can't use async/await, even if I wanted, again it does not solve the problem.
I could use `Task.FromAsync` but you can refer to a problem I have hit on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499646/webrequest-begingetresponse-endgetresponse-throws-exception-when-using-task-from)
I can't use a 3rd party library since this is a library and don't want 3rd party dependencies.

There really is a reason this should be synchronously, won't get into details, it's not a design problem, it's a design feature.

Using the WebRequest Begin/End operations, Request/Response happens with callbacks.
That's great and works fine. Now there is no API to make a call synchronously to a web service, GetRequest/GetRespone are not supported in the Windows Phone 8 SDK.

I have tried to use a Mutex and to call a `Wait` method which inside the web service class calls `Mutex.WaitOne()` supposed it will pause the calling method until the last callback that finishes the request and get the response will signal to free.

Theoretically it should work, but when calling `WaitOne()`, the last callback never returns to do the job.

Then I thought using `IAsyncResult` return value from BeginXyz/EndXyz methods check for `IsComplete` in a while loop and break to continue if true. No success.

So, I wonder, is there a feasible efficient solution to synchronously call a web service?

Searching Google and stackoverflow, returned no working solution.

**Updated**

Here is some code I tried:

```
    public void ExecuteRequest(string url, string requestData, string filePath)
            {
                    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
                    request.Method = "POST";
                    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    ((HttpWebRequest)request).UserAgent = "Tester";
                    request.Headers["UserName"] = "Tester";

                    DataWebRequest webRequestState = new DataWebRequest
                    {
                        Data = requestData,
                        FileName = filePath,
                        Request = request
                    };

                    IAsyncResult requestResult = request.BeginGetRequestStream(ar =>
                    {
                        DataWebRequest webRequestData = (DataWebRequest )ar.AsyncState;
                        HttpWebRequest requestStream = (HttpWebRequest)webRequestData.Request;

                        string data = webRequestData.Data;

                        // Convert the string into a byte array.
                        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

                        try
                        {
                            // End the operation
// Here the EndGetRequestStream(ar) throws exception System.InvalidOperationException: 
// Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
                            using (Stream endGetRequestStream = requestStream.EndGetRequestStream(ar))
                            {
                                // Write to the request stream.
                                endGetRequestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                            }

                            requestStream.BeginGetResponse(GetResponseCallback, webRequestData);
                        }
                        catch (WebException webEx)
                        {
                            WebExceptionStatus status = webEx.Status;
                            WebResponse responseEx = webEx.Response;
                            Debug.WriteLine(webEx.ToString());
                        }
                    }, webRequestState);

    // The below while loop is actually breaking as the IsCompleted is true, but an
    // exception System.InvalidOperationException is thrown after a while
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (requestResult.IsCompleted) break;
                    }

                    IAsyncResult responseResult = request.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
                    {
                        DataWebRequest webRequestData = (DataWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
                        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)webRequestData.Request;

                        try
                        {
                            // End the operation
                            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(ar))
                            {
                                HttpStatusCode rcode = response.StatusCode;
                                Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
                                StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);

                                // The Response
                                string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

                                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(webRequestData.FileName))
                                {
                                    FileRepository fileRepo = new FileRepository();
                                    fileRepo.Delete(webRequestData.FileName);
                                }

                                Debug.WriteLine("Response : {0}", responseString);

                                // Maybe do some other stuff....
                            }
                        }
                        catch (WebException webEx)
                        {
                            WebExceptionStatus status = webEx.Status;
                            WebResponse responseEx = webEx.Response;
                            Debug.WriteLine(webEx.ToString());
                        }

                    }, webRequestState);

    // This while loop never actually ends!!!
                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (responseResult.IsCompleted) break;
                    }
            }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Show us your code that's not working.  It's the only hope of your question being meaningfully answered.

Comment: I have manipulated the code so many time that now it's just asynchronous. But give me some minutes to prepare it. I'll do the most logical solution using the IAsyncResult return and check the IsCompleted property.

Comment: You can see some code I've tried, not sure if it's the right way though!

Comment: can't you just use the Synchronous calls, ie. `GetRequestStream` instead of `BeginGetRequestStream` etc

Comment: Have you ever used the WebRequest to make a web service call in Windows Phone 8? There is no such methods. Only APM methods available.